# Reason and solution of my code which is giving segmentation fault in C program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int display(int arr[], int n);
int main()
{
    int i, n;

    printf("\nEnter the Size of Array:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];

    printf("\nEnter the %d Values of Arrays", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    display(&arr[0], n);
    return 0;
}

int display(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("\nThe %d elements are:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Array [%d]= %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
}
```

---

This is the code for printing the array values using function. And in Run-time it gives Segmentation fault error. Help me to fix this.

Comment: `scanf("%d", arr[i]);` should be `scanf("%d", &arr[i]);` you forgot the `&`

Comment: Turn up the warning levels in your compiler, it should have noticed this.

Comment: Your edit only fixed one of the problems @Barmar pointed out. Strangely enough, you fixed the one he did not mention but forgot to fix the one he actually mentioned :-) Sidenote: Never use `scanf` without checking that it actually succeeds too.

Comment: The usual way to write the `display` call is `display(arr, n)`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo edits to code in questions are **not supposed to** fix the cause of the  problem that is actually being asked about, **even if** it's a typo. On the rare occasions that the question doesn't get closed as a typo (perhaps because it's exemplary of a common error, that might be underpinned by a *conceptual* problem that can be asked about), the code in the question needs to actually demonstrate the problem (be a [mre]).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree 100%. I just explained to OP why the problem persisted even though the code had been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the address of the variable when calling `scanf()` in the loop, just as you do when reading `n`.

When passing an array to a function, we usually just write the name of the array. This is equivalent to passing `&arr[0]`, but we don't normally write that out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int display(int arr[], int n);
int main()
{
    int i, n;

    printf("\nEnter the Size of Array:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];

    printf("\nEnter the %d Values of Arrays", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    display(arr, n);
    return 0;
}

int display(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("\nThe %d elements are:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Array [%d]= %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
}
```